# Conditional Statement add css in them

Tags: css, conditional-comments

Is it possible to do the following with conditional comments:

```
<!--[if IE]>
   .ie-only{margin-top:-13px;}
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Have you tried it? I assume _not_ as these comment tags usually contains links to CSS files, so at least you need to wrap it in a `style` or something. But this would be easy to test if you want to. Now, the question of whether you _need_ to these days...

Comment: @somethinghere I tried and it didnt work

Comment: Whatdoes that tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this...

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!--[if IE]>
  <style>
    .box {  
        width: 500px;  
        background:red;
        padding: 100px 0;  
      }  
  </style>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">Try this in IE</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:**

You can also include external css for IE alone.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="onlyfoie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank You

Comment: That actually worked, thanks

Comment: glad to be help... Accept this as a answer if it helped...